# How to compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors recursively

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, change-of-basis

I would like to write an algorithm (albeit inefficient) using the following algorithm.

I don't know whether this algorithm already has a name.  If so what is the name of the algorithm, or a link to it?

Algorithm:

1. Given an $n\times n$ matrix $A_n$ find (if possible) one eigenvalue/eigenvector pair $(\lambda_n, b_n)$.
2. Produce a smaller matrix, $A_{n-1}$, of dimension $(n-1)
       \times (n-1)$ whose eigenvalues are the *other*
   eigenvalues of $A_n$.
3. With a recursive call, find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A_{n-1}$.
4. Convert the $(n-1)$ dimensional eigenvectors
   of $A_{n-1}$ back to $n$-dimensional eigenvectors of $A_n$.

Questions:

1. Given $A_n$, $\lambda_n$, and $b_n$, how can I produce $A_{n-1}$ (of size $(n-1)\times(n-1)$) whose eigenvalues are the *other* eigenvalues of $A_n$.
2. Given a set of eigenvalue/eigenvector pairs of $A_{n-1}$, how can I produce the remaining eigenvectors of $A_n$.

Vague unknowns:

It seems to me that such an algorithm is possible and straightforward. I need to somehow perform a change of coordinates so that $b_n$ is translated to $[1, 0, \ldots, 0]$, and $A_n$ is converted to a matrix with $0$s in the first row (?and first column?) and a $1$ in the upper-left.  Then take the sub-matrix simply removing the first row and column of $A_n$.  After I get the eigenvectors of $A_{n-1}$, I need to change the coordinates back to the original coordinate system, I.e., convert $[1, 0, \ldots, 0]$ back to $b_n$.

But I don't know if this will work, how to change the coordinates, whether the submatrix will have the same eigenvalues, or whether I will need to somehow scale them by the change-of-cordinate matrix.

Comment: Conceptually, it is obvious how to do this when the matrix is normal, because then you can just restrict to the orthogonal complement of the span of the eigenvectors you have already found in your search for the next one. Otherwise it isn't obvious what subspace you look in for your next eigenvector. The workaround in the non-normal case is harder to explain without a bunch of technical details. The starting point is similarity transformations to get to upper Hessenberg form, then after that it depends more on the method.